# Ubuntu 12.10 and Gnome-Shell : can't see nor launch apps except with Alt + F2

Tags: gnome

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 and Gnome-Shell 3.6.

Everything worked fine till the moment I've began to customize the main menu (apps wich appears in Dash and so on).

I don't know wether I've done something wrong or if there is a bug : suddenly, the Dash became empty. My favourite docks too, except the "Show apps" button. When I activate it, there is only an empty dash, no apps showed.
The only way I can access an app is using the "Alt+F2" shortcut. 
I've tried to restart gnome-shell (Alt-F2 / r) but nothing has changed...
A logout and a reboot have not changed ...

Do you know how to repair the gnome-shell ?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing what you mean by the 'dash' ('overview' maybe?) or how you tried to customize which apps appear (which programs you used, ...).

Comment: Excuse me : I mean the overview... Gnome-Shell displays none apps in the overview. All my favourites disappear too. It seems to be a config problem: I've re-installed the OS, and the problem remains...Unity works well.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've discovered that the problem came from Alacarte (menus). 
I've found the solution in the Archlinux Forum, [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=137590).
It seems that Alacarte creates a ~/.config/menus folder. When deleting this folder, Gnome-Shell recoveres its usual Apps overview and the customized Favourite Ones.

Thanks a lot for your interest and answers...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same with Gnome-shell on ubuntu 12.10. (with gnome2)

It used to work with "gnome" & "gnome classic (no effects)"

To make it work with "gnome classic" ((my preferred window manager), I had to follow below steps.

[compizconfig-settings-manager [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager)
[image: Install via the software center]

1. `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. On command line/alt+f2 enter ccsm (or open compizconfig-settings-manager from applications menu)
3. On left side categories, select window management.
4. Select your preferred window switcher. & Enable it.

I hope it helps someone. I had struggled for 2-3 hrs for it. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Anishane ! I've not tried with ccsm... as i've finally found that Alacarte was the problem (see my answer above). I do hope your answer will help some others...